# How to update one view from within another in SwiftUI

Tags: mvvm, swiftui

I am working on a SwiftUI view where I have it populates other subviews within the main view. My question is how can I call something in the main view from within a sub view?

Here is what the code looks like for my main view:

```
struct MovieList: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = MovieViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                VStack {
                    ForEach(self.viewModel.movie) { movie in
                        MovieView(movie: movie)
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Movies")
        .onAppear {
            self.viewModel.fetchMovies() // Fetch all movies and cause entire view to refresh and populate movies
        }
    }
}
```

This main view populates a list of movies by adding multiple MovieView instances.

Here is some example code for the MovieView:

```
struct MovieView: View {
    
      
    let movie: Movie
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            
            HStack {
                Text(“Movie Title: \(movie.title)”)
            }.padding([.top, .leading, .bottom])
            
              
           Button("Do not show this movie") {
            // Update user prefers to hide the movie.
            // But also somehow from within here call viewModel.fetchMovies() in the other view to refresh the movies list
      }


        }
    }
}
```

So for example, from within one of the MovieView views, how can I have fetchMovies() from within the main view called so that everything gets updated?

Essentially a list of items is being populated and I would like for any one of these to have the ability to refresh/ perform some action on the entire main view

Comment: Instead of let movie use Binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of updating the `Movie` itself, as was pointed out in the comments, you probably want to pass a `Binding` to it. See the changes to the `ForEach`.

In terms of calling `fetchMovies` again, you can either pass the entire `ObservableObject` to the child view or just pass a reference to the function you need (which I've shown below):

```
struct Movie : Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title : String
    var isHidden: Bool
}

class MovieViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var movies = [Movie]()
    
    func fetchMovies() {
        //fetch
    }
}

struct MovieList: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = MovieViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                VStack {
                    ForEach($viewModel.movies) { $movie in
                        MovieView(movie: $movie, fetchMovies: viewModel.fetchMovies)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Movies")
        .onAppear {
            self.viewModel.fetchMovies()
        }
    }
}

struct MovieView: View {
    @Binding var movie: Movie
    var fetchMovies : () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            
            HStack {
                Text("Movie Title: \(movie.title)")
            }.padding([.top, .leading, .bottom])
            
            
            Button("Do not show this movie") {
                movie.isHidden = true
                fetchMovies()
            }
        }
    }
}
```